# Property of closed sets

Tags: probability, general-topology

I am currently studying John Kingman's "Poisson Processes" and stumbled upon the following statements: "Every open set $G$ is a countable union of disjoint intervals $A_j$, and then $N(G) =$ $\sum N(A_j)$ is a random variable if the $N(A_j)$ are. (1)

Every closed set $F$ is the intersection of a decreasing sequence of open sets $G_i$, and $N(F)$ is the limit of the decreasing sequence of $N(G_i)$ ". (2)

I fail to understand why the first part of (2) is true, but I suppose the second part follows from the sigma-continuity of the $N(G_i)$, provided $N(F)$ is a random variable. I am grateful for any tip or piece of advice regarding the first part of (2), i.e. showing that every closed set $F$ is the intersection of a decreasing sequence of open sets.

Comment: I think $N$ itself is not a random variable.  For each (Borel?) set $A$, there is a random variable $N(A)$.  See the definitions for "Poisson process" earlier in your reference.

Comment: Yes you are right I will edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true in any metric space. If $F$ is a closed set in a metric space then $F$ is the intersection of the sets $G_n=\{x: d(x,F) <\frac 1 n\}$ where $d(x,F)=\inf \{d(x,y): y \in F\}$. Also,  each $G_n$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

First part of (2):

Take 
$$
G_j = \{x \colon \inf_{y\in F} |x - y| < 1/j\}
$$
[suppose we are working on $\mathbb R$].

Answer (score 1):

You can take
$$ F_{k} = \left\{ x+y \, : \, x \in F, \, |y| < \frac{1}{k}  \right\}, $$
so that $F_k \supset F_{k+1}$ for all $k \geq 1$, and
$$ \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k = F. $$